# Installing Heroku CLI on macOS Catalina

Tags: terminal, command-line

Let me just state what has already been tried and what is already known. When I downloaded and tried to run the installer, the following error pops up:

> "Currently, the macOS installer on Catalina displays an “unknown author” warning. We are working to address this."

So I tried other methods such as running the following in the terminal:

```
sudo snap install --classic heroku
```

and

```
curl https://cli-assets.heroku.com/install.sh | sh
```

but both required some sort of superuser access, password required (which I have no idea what it is).

I have also downloaded the macOS tarballs but I have no idea how it works too.

Could somebody provide some advice? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The Heroku CLI is available to install via Homebrew. [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) is a 3rd party, community supported package manager for macOS.

If you have Homebrew installed, simply run the following command-line to install Heroku CLI ([instructions here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli)):

```
brew tap heroku/brew && brew install heroku
```

If you do not already have Homebrew installed, install it by running the following command-line ([instructions here](https://brew.sh)):

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Using Homebrew provides a seamless and hassle-free experience for installing supported 3rd party packages such as the one in question.

Comment: I have also tried exploring that (I don't have Homebrew installed yet, so I followed the 2nd instruction). After copy and pasting ```/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"``` into terminal, I get asked about my password once again, which I have no idea! If it helps, I did not set any password at all to my MacBook user login... so I really don't know what password it is asking for.

Comment: @user12575866 Are you logged in with an Admin account or a Standard one? If unsure, go to System Preferences app → Users & Groups and check what does the subtext under your user account name displays.

Comment: I am an Admin account. the word "Admin" is under my user..

Comment: @user12575866 Consider setting a password for your account. It could be done from the same System Preference pane. Once set, enter this same password when prompted for in the Terminal app.

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes it does work now, after setting a password. Thanks once again!